# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, socketexception

I have a problem here. Every time I launch my test program I seem to get a SocketException. Localhost og IP:127.0.0.1 works no problem, and the firewall is down when I test. The error comes both when I am at my Akademy and at home.

PS. It's a C# Console Application written in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

====SOURCE CODE====

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MasserAfTesting {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int port = 2520;
            string ip = "91.236.210.60";

            new Thread(new Manager(port).Run).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            new Thread(new Client(ip, port).Run).Start();
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MasserAfTesting {
    class Manager {
        private int port;


        public Manager(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void Run() {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(port);
            listener.Start();
            while (true) {
                new Thread(new Worker(listener.AcceptTcpClient()).Run).Start();
            }
        }

    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MasserAfTesting {
    class Worker {
        private TcpClient client;

        public Worker(TcpClient client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void Run() {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Worker Online...");
        }

    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MasserAfTesting {
    class Client {

        TcpClient client;

        public Client(string ip, int port) {
            this.client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        }

        public void Run() {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Client online...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the details of the socket exception? Any inner exceptions? Detail? Please post.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. When you push the `Ask Question` button, you are supposed to actually ask a question.

Comment: Dude, read the text again. The question is embedded in the text. "I get a socketexception" that basically screams "WHY!?!"

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. For all we know, you might be wanting the socketexception to show up in the console using red text. We may seem to be coming down on you, but it helps us a lot if you, A) Describe the situation (you did), B) Let us know what you tried (you did, regarding localhost, the firewall and using two different computers), and then finally C) Ask the question. Sometimes the very act of writing the question helps formulate it in your mind and triggers a thought that might present you the solution. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/15/1883515.aspx